# how to fetch correctly XML from a server in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, parsing, kotlin, okhttp

In iOS development, when I fetch an URL that displays XML, I can parse the whole XML file and use its data in my code, but in Kotlin I tried fetching the same URL and it returns only the first XML tag, like if the rest was hidden in the main tag.

```
    val urlString = URL_TO_FETCH_IN_HTTPS (String)
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(urlString).build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body?.string()

                println("RESPONSE " + body)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Failure")
        }
    })
```

The response of this call is just

```
RESPONSE < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>< rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Although the url is good, and the returned XML in a browser is also good.

**So what do I do wrong in the code? How can I fetch the whole XML at this url?**

I used the library OkHttp for fetching data from a URL

Comment: What do you mean by the whole XML ? what response do you expect?

Comment: I expect to retrieve the content of the xml, at this link https://lexilife.com/rss
With all the data that I can parse. It is a xml file returned by a Prestashop API

Comment: Are you sure you correctly install prestashop ? are you sure to use the correct apikey? and you can also try to add ?output_format=JSON like this : https://UCCLLQ9N2ARSHWCXLT74KUKSSK34BFKX@example.com/api/?output_format=JSON
To get json format that might be more usable than xml. i got no problem fetching data in my side. Also did you try to add the interceptor as i suggested ? it's realy simple to debug

Comment: OK my bad, Newbie mistake ^^
The thing is that the response of my log is "RESPONSE < ?xml version...Atom">" because when I searched for the log in the logcat, I typed "RESPONSE" in the search bar so it gave me only the first line...

In iOS it would have written the whole object next to the "RESPONSE" word in the log

Comment: OK good luck with you project, anyways try to add interceptor for okhttp it's only few line that i gave you and it's very convenient.

Comment: Yes I will do for sure, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

First of all to debug Okhttp i would suggest to add an interceptor :

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
```

Then build you client like this to first add interceptor and have handle timeout :

```
 client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
```

Then you can : `client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {` ...

By doing so you can easily debug Okhttp you will have on the log the request that you made with the parameter send + then response of the server with the code and the body. All call are writen in blue for better visibilitie.

if you still got probleme don't hesitate to ask.

More over you should look at retrofit2 it's an easy lib to handle all apicall.